# Netbeans 14 - Won't Let Me Activate Java Web and EE

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I can't activate the Java Web and EE. I'm trying to start a project using Glassfish. Currently using Apache Netbeans 14.

[image]

Comment: Try activating Java SE first? Also, update your question to specify the version of Java being used.

Comment: [1] I am also using NetBeans 14 and **Base IDE** is shown as installed but not active, yet if I check that entry my only option is to click **Uninstall**. That's not directly relevant to your question, but I see that you have successful activated **Base IDE**. [2] In my case, however, I can and have activated **Java Web and EE**. [3] So there is some evidence of a possible issue with plugin activation in NetBeans 14. Beyond raising it as [an issue with NetBeans on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/3447) I have no suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to uninstall netbeans and re-install then try activating Java Web & EE .
Sometimes other 3rd party installed plugins creates issue with main features . Before uninstalling take a backup of all your projects in your system .
If the issue still persists then try to downgrade it to netbeans 12 or in the worst case Netbeans 8.2.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was I was running NetBeans 18, which requires Java 11+, with Java 8.

Once I modified netbeans.conf with the proper JDK path, plugin activation came back to life.

Comment: FYI: you can [delete your previous post](/help/deleted-questions), given it's not an answer. Also there's the possibility of [edit]ing post, which you could've done instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: This answer does not seem relevant for this question, which was about NetBeans 14.

Comment: Do as you want. My problem is already resolve and you are doing the "answer to the problem" absolutely irrelevant.